# How to write LSP client to communicate with LSP server in java

Tags: eclipse, language-server-protocol

I have UI application which is built as Elcipse Plugin/SWT. Currently there are some validations from UI [a form], currently done with simple validation rule classes. I wanted to move this to LSP based validation. I am able to write an LSP server. However I have no idea how to write a LSP client which should be invoked from a JAva class(SWT). Please help me

Comment: Possibly [Eclipse LSP4J](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.lsp4j)

Comment: @greg-449. I assume We use LSP4J for creating LSP server. For client we should use LSP4E

Comment: @TechUser In my understanding, LSP4J is the non Eclipse-specific core implementation for both, language server and client. LSP4E which does not provide a language server itself is also [based on LSP4J](https://git.eclipse.org/c/lsp4e/lsp4e.git/tree/org.eclipse.lsp4e/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#n31). Look at the code of LSP4E to understand how to use LSP4J.